# How do I merge thousands of json files with jq?

Tags: json, windows, cmd, jq, cmder

I have thousands of individually named `json` files in a single windows directory. I'm trying to use `jq` to merge them all into a single file I can then import into a jupyter notebook.

I keep getting a permissioned denied error when I try and run the following command:

`jq --slurp 'map(.[])' bill`

I've tried editing the directory (bill) permissions. My file path looks like this:

`\downloadedJSONfiles\AK\2019-2020_31st_Legislature\bill`

I downloaded `jq` through `chocolately`. I'm using `cmder`

Comment: Can you use `bill/*` or change directory to `bill` and use `*` in place of `bill`?

Comment: Rather than creating a monster JSON, would it be possible to use PyPi's jsonlines (https://pypi.org/project/jsonlines)?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting permission denied because you provided a directory where a path to an ordinary file is expected.

---

I'm going to start with the "unix" approach because jq has unix roots. The following is the command you want to use:

```bash
jq --slurp 'map(.[])' bill/a.json bill/b.json bill/c.json ...
```

The shell will expand the following command into the above:

```bash
jq --slurp 'map(.[])' bill/*.json
```

The problem  is that this can easily result in a command that's too long. So you really want one the following:

```bash
# A
(
   jq '.[]' bill/a.json
   jq '.[]' bill/b.json
   jq '.[]' bill/c.json
   jq '.[]' bill/d.json
   jq '.[]' bill/e.json
   jq '.[]' bill/f.json
) | jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# B
(
   cat bill/a.json
   cat bill/b.json
   cat bill/c.json
   cat bill/d.json
   cat bill/e.json
   cat bill/f.json
) | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'
```

```bash
# C
(
   jq '.[]' bill/a.json bill/b.json bill/c.json
   jq '.[]' bill/d.json bill/e.json bill/f.json
) | jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# D
(
   cat bill/a.json bill/b.json bill/c.json
   cat bill/d.json bill/e.json bill/f.json
) | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'
```

Something equivalent can be achieved using any of the following:

```bash
# Portable. Equivalent to A
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -exec jq '.[]' {} \; | jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# Portable. Equivalent to B
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -exec cat {} \; | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'
```

```bash
# Possibly portable with tweaks. Similar to "C"
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -print0 |
   xargs -r0 jq '.[]' |
      jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# Possibly portable with tweaks. Similar to "D"
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -print0 |
   xargs -r0 cat |
      jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# GNU-specific. Equivalent to "C"
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -exec jq '.[]' {} + | jq --slurp .
```

```bash
# GNU-specific. Equivalent to "D"
find bill -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -exec cat {} + | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'
```

---

But you asked about Windows. In the Windows world it's up to programs to perform their own wildcard expansion. So you'd expect to be able to do

```bash
jq --slurp 'map(.[])' bill\*.json
```

However, `jq` wasn't properly ported.

```
Assertion failed!

Program: c:\bin\jq.exe
File: src/main.c, Line 256

Expression: wargc == argc
```

So like in unix, you have to pass all the files you want to process to `jq` as separate arguments.

Using `cmd`, you could use either of the following:

```
:: Not efficient
copy /y nul bill.jsonl
for %q in (bill\*.json) do jq ".[]" %q >>bill.jsonl
jq --slurp . bill.jsonl
del bill.jsonl
```

```
:: More efficient
copy /y nul+bill\*.json bill.jsonl
jq --slurp "map(.[])" bill.jsonl
del bill.jsonl
```

---

PowerShell is a far more advanced shell than `cmd`. With PowerShell, you could use

```
jq --slurp 'map(.[])' ( Get-Item bill\*.json )
```

But just like the simple unix version, the above can easily result in a command line that's too long. To avoid that, we can use the following:

```
# Not efficient
Get-Item bill\*.json | %{ jq '.[]' $_ } | jq --slurp .
```

```
# More efficient
%{ Get-Content bill\*.json } | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'
```

(`%{...}` is a shorthand for `ForEach-Object {...}`.)

---

Finally, I'm not familiar with Cmder.

Comment: `Get-Content` works with wilddcards so this would work: `Get-Content bill\*.json | jq --slurp 'map(.[])'`

Comment: @PerseP Thanks, incorporated that simplification. I'm not a familiar with PS.